# How to stop Chrome throw unresponsive error?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a JavaScript + HTML program which includes a function taking long time to execute. The problem is, when I run this program on Chrome, Chrome throws unresponsive alert about 20 seconds after the long-time-taking-function starts its process. It is really annoying because I have to click wait button to delete the alert. Is it possible to make the unresponsive alert disabled by changing configuration of Chrome or by inserting some snippet in my JavaScript code?

Any information would be appreciated.

### addition

I am sorry for not adding any code. My code is a bit complicated so I don't come up with a minimal reproducible example of my attempt. But I'm trying and please wait for a while.

Comment: Add the code...

Comment: Use a web worker: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers You are exactly describing the use-case for a web worker, a long-running background task

Comment: Chances are there's something wrong with your code, but we can't see it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: In short, no. There's nothing you can do to disable the unresponsive alert other than "fixing" your code. Take a look at web workers as @jabaa suggests

Answer (score 2):

No, the warning is just telling you that the browser is unresponsive. Disabling the warning wouldn't solve the underlying problem.

If you have long-running scripts (anything over a couple milliseconds should be considered long-running, your 20 second script would definitely be considered long-running), you should use asynchronous techniques: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Essentially your code will ask for a 'Promise' which then works in the background without stalling your browser or blocking other code. When it's resolved, the promise will come back to your code and you can use the results.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the browser  evaluates whether it throws the `unresponsive warning` by how much time has passed from a certain process starts, but it seemed to be just my assumption. I'd like to learn asynchronous and Promise.